# How to Handle Multiple Click Events In Android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I already watched so many tutorials about how to press a button and play a sound for that button with an event. My question here is:
If I want to create a list of tones(Example Do,Re,Mi,Fa,...) and a list of musical instruments. Then I have to create these number of events, events = tone*instr. That is too much for a small app. So how can I reduce the number of events?

Comment: If I am not mistaken. The "event" you are talking about is the onClickListener, right?

Comment: yes. and is this possible if just one onClick event can push many button with difference tone?

Comment: As @EpicNinja has been pointing out you can associate multiple button the same [`View.OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and get the view ID [`getId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) in the event to differentiate between the buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement onClickListener in your Activity. Set onClickListener for each button. Then just detect the corresponding button pressed.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
     Button button1, button2;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

          button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

          button1.setOnClickListener(this);
          button2.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          if(v == button1)
          {
             //play button1 sound
          }

          else if(v == button2)
          {
             //play button2 sound
          }

          else 
          {
             ......
          }
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome. please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: i'm so sorry cause i'm a newbie then can't get enough to vote you up :<

Comment: I am not asking you to vote me. Just accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: it's really helpful with me. And i have another question, does this Onclick event works if i'm going push 2 or 3 button at the same time? i means the chords .